# how to chage navbar items with respect to user roles from master page code behind in c# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, code-behind, roles

I'm working on a website project in visual studio 2013..

I've some items in my navbar one of them is "manage" which I want it to take the user if he is an admin to some page and if he is a committee to another page and so on.. I've used the following code but I got this exception:

> (An exception of type '`System.NullReferenceException`' occurred in
>   App_Web_2g0memkh.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

does any one have an idea to fix this problem?

Site.master :

```
<LoggedInTemplate>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" runat="server" id="list">
        <li id="A1" runat="server"><a runat="server" title="Go To Control Page" href="~/Admin/control.aspx">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %></a></li>
        <li id="A2" runat="server"><a runat="server" title="Go To Control Page" href="~/Committee/control.aspx">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %></a></li>
        <li id="A3" runat="server" ><a runat="server" title="Manage your account" href="~/Account/Manage">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %></a></li>
        <li><asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" /></li>
    </ul>
</LoggedInTemplate>
```

Site.master.cs : ( I was testing only for the admin )

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        HtmlGenericControl li1 = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("A1");
        li1.Visible = true;
        HtmlGenericControl li2 = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("A2");
        li2.Visible = false;
        HtmlGenericControl li3 = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("A3");
        li3.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is with the  tag !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thank you I solved my problem =) it was in the LoggedInTemplate and I did its function programmatically ... if someone wants to gets benefit this is my solution ...

I canceled the asp:LoginView, and logged in template. Then I gave an id to the ul tag and runnat="server" as follows

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" runat="server" id="LoggedIn" visible="False">

    <li id="A1" runat="server"><a runat="server" title="Go To Control Page" href="~/Admin/control.aspx">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %></a></li>
    <li id="A2" runat="server"><a runat="server" title="Go To Control Page" href="~/Committee/control.aspx">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %></a></li>
    <li id="A3" runat="server"><a runat="server" title="Manage your account" href="~/Account/Manage">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %></a></li>
    <li>
         <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

and my codebehind inside Page_Load:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        LoggedIn.Visible = true;
        if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            A1.Visible = true;
            A2.Visible = false;
            A3.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are doing this:

```
HtmlGenericControl li1 = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("A1");
li1.Visible = true;
```

just call them directly

```
if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    A1.Visible = true;
    A2.Visible = false;
    A3.Visible = false;
}
```

it works for me

Comment: yes I tried this before, but didn't work it works fine with the web forms ( means the normal .aspx pages ) but it doesn't work with the master page ... it gives me this error:

 Error 1 The name 'A1' does not exist in the current context